# Symfony2 + Doctrine2 - select on many to many relationship

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm, symfony-2.8

I have problem with selecting data from DB with many to many relationship.

I have news on page. Each news, in spite of other fields, have two interesting cols - type (string) and category. Each news can have many categories. I have no problem with saving news with many categories when adding in admin. But then - we have users who log in on page and each user have assigned categories. When user is logged in and have assigned categories, I should take from DB only news with user selected categories and other news (type != 'news').

**News.php** entity

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\Category", inversedBy="news")
 * @ORM\JoinTable(name="news_categories")
 */
private $categories;
```

**Category.php** entity

```
/**
 *
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\News", mappedBy="category")
 */
private $news;
```

I'm collecting news in news repository:

```
$query = $this->createQueryBuilder('p');
    if($user->hasCategories()) {
        $query
            ->innerJoin('p.category', 'c')
            ->andWhere('p.type != :paramType OR (c.id IN (:categoryIds) AND p.type = :paramType)')
            ->setParameter(':categoryIds', $categories)
            ->setParameter(':paramType', 'news');
    }
    $result = $query->getQuery()->getResult();
```

When I log in with user with no categories assigned - I'm getting all news. Not going into "if" statement, it works just fine.
When I'm logged in with user with assigned categories, I'm getting only news with type "news" with user assigned categories, but no other news (with type != 'news').

What am I doing wrong?

Once again, goal is to get all data from news table if user with no assigned categories (no problem) and take only news with type = 'news' and defined categories if logged in user has assigned categories.

Thanks.

Comment: Changed innerJoin to leftJoin and it works as expected.